# Git hooks do not run

Tags: git, githooks

I want to run `post-receive` hook to notify Jenkins to start a new build, but I cannot make Git hooks to run automatically.

1. I tried example hooks in `.git/hooks` repository, by removing `.sample` but none of them run after the actions they are supposed to do so.
2. I have setup hooks path to `.git/hooks` using `git config --local core.hooksPath .git/hooks` command, but it did not help.
3. I made sure hooks scripts are executable (`chmod ug+x <script>`).

Is there some special setup required to run Git hooks automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post-receive` hook is a server-side hook. It is invoked when data is pushed to the repository. You can simulate the process with two local repositories, one as the client and the other as the server.

```
git init --bare server
# copy post-receive to server/hooks and make sure it's executable

git init client
cd client
touch a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit
git push ../server master
```

In practice, the server-side repository is usually at another machine, and we use http/https-protocol or ssh-protocol remote to communicate with it. The hook should be installed in the server-side repository.

Then there is another issue. In most cases, the server-side repositories are managed by a hosting service like Github, Gitlab, Gitee or other services. They may support the standard git hooks like `post-receive` and may not. They have their own hooks, like [Github webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks), different from git hooks. For these hooks, reference the documentation to find how to configure and use them.